# Custom Object Relationship query behaves differently in Test from Execute Anonymous

Tags: apex, unit-test, custom-object, failing-tests, execute-anonymous

### Background

I have a custom object `Contact_Coverage__c`. I have a custom field `Contact_Coverage__c` added to the `Activity` standard object, with the child relationship name `Activities__r`. In general, I am able to find all associated `Task` records to a `Contact_Coverage__c` record using a standard relationship query, e.g.:

```
List<Contact_Coverage__c> ccList = [
    SELECT (
        SELECT Id
        FROM Activities__r
    )
    FROM Contact_Coverage__c
]
Integer howManyTasks = ccList.Activities__r.size();
```

### Failing test

When I use this in a test, however, it is failing:

```
@isTest static void withCustomObject(){
    User u = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
    String random = String.valueOf(Math.random()); // to avoid dupes
    Account a = new Account(Name = 'Company, LLC' + random);
    insert a;
    Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'Smith' + random, AccountId = a.Id);
    insert c;
    Contact_Coverage__c cc = new Contact_Coverage__c(
        Sales_Coverage__c = u.Id,
        Contact__c = c.Id,
        Coverage__c = '30'
    );
    insert cc;
    Task t = new Task(
        ActivityDate = System.Today(),
        Contact_Coverage__c = cc.Id
    );
    insert t;
    List<Task> tasks = [
        SELECT Contact_Coverage__c
        FROM Task
        WHERE Contact_Coverage__c = :cc.Id
    ];
    List<Contact_Coverage__c> contactCoverages = [
        SELECT (
            SELECT Id
            FROM Activities__r
        )
        FROM Contact_Coverage__c
    ];
    System.assertEquals(cc.Id, tasks[0].Contact_Coverage__c);
    System.assertEquals(1,contactCoverages[0].Activities__r.Size());
}
```

I would expect this to pass no problem. But the first `assertEquals` is passing, and the second `assertEquals` is failing.

### Works fine with a Standard Object

When I do something very similar with `Account` instead of my custom object, it works as expected:

```
@isTest static void withStandardObject(){
    String random = String.valueOf(Math.random()); // to avoid dupes
    Account a = new Account(Name = 'Company, LLC' + random);
    insert a;
    Task t = new Task(
        ActivityDate = System.Today(),
        WhatId = a.Id
    );
    insert t;
    List<Task> tasks = [
        SELECT WhatId
        FROM Task
        WHERE WhatId = :a.Id
    ];
    List<Account> accounts = [
        SELECT (
            SELECT Id
            FROM Tasks
        )
        FROM Account
    ];
    System.assertEquals(a.Id, tasks[0].WhatId);
    System.assertEquals(1,accounts[0].Tasks.Size());
}
```

### But passing in Execute Anonymous???

I would chalk this up to something wrong with my Custom Object, except that when I use this exact code (except not in a test method) in execute anonymous, both asserts pass! That's the reason I have the random string there, so I can run this without having to delete the newly generated Contact and Account each time.

## Question

WTF is going on here? Is this a known quirk? Could it be some trigger or flow I don't know about (this is a 10 year old org and I've only been here a few months)? And if so, why the heck does it only happen in testing??

*Note: This test as I'm providing it here obviously isn't testing anything, I just limited it down to the part that's confusing me.*

Comment: if something works in exec anon but not in apex - it is most likely a version issue as exec anon always uses latest version

Comment: @cropredy that solved it, if you'd like to make it an answer I can mark it correct. Specifically, the Apex class was set to API version 38.0, and when I set it to 42.0 it worked as expected (like exec anon)

Comment: You're comparing different child lists. One is `Tasks` (child type `Task`) and the other is a magical related list `Activities__r` (child types `Task` *and* `Event`). Have you tried using `Activities` on `Account` or tried `Tasks__r` on your custom object?

Comment: @AdrianLarson You can't add new custom fields directly to Task, which is why I added it on Activity. See this answer: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gjGHAAY

Answer (score 3):

When something works in `execute anonymous` but does not work in a testmethod, the typical reason is difference in version.

Execute Anonymous always operates in the latest version, including the sandbox preview version if yo are executing in such a sandbox.

Try aligning your testmethod and underlying classes to be the current version.

As for the commentary on custom fields on Tasks vs Activities - this is just a UI artifice presented by SFDC. Activity Custom Fields end up on the concrete Task and Event objects.

You can't do SOQL `...FROM Activity ...`, instead, you do SOQL `...FROM Task...` or `...FROM Event ...`

You also have OOTB access to certain related lists for subselects

```
select ..., (select ID, ... FROM Events), ... FROM parentSobject
select ..., (select ID, ... FROM Tasks), ... FROM parentSobject
select ..., (select ID, ... FROM ActivityHistories), ... FROM parentSobject
```

*where `parentSObject` is any Sobject defined to support Activities.*

plus any custom lookup relationships you defined on Task or Event to some specific parentSObject